# Finding an approximation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series

I want to find an approximation that allows me to calculate $x$. I would be grateful if someone can help me.
I have already figured out that it can be done using numerical methods like Newton's or bisection method. For $s\in N$, and $\beta\in (0,1)$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{s} \frac{x^k}{k!}e^{-x}=\beta
\end{equation}

In other words, $F(s,x)=\beta$, where $F(s,x)$ is Poisson cumulative distribution function at point $s$ with mean $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) gives it as $\frac {\Gamma(s+1,\lambda)}{s!}$ (using your variables) where I took off the floor brackets assuming $s$ is natural.  $\Gamma(s+1,\lambda)$ is the incomplete Gamma function.  Section 6.2 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) gives an algorithm for the incomplete Gamma function.